# Tensorflow/XLA: number of parallel operations in the LLVM IR

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

I am interested in the LLVM IR obtained launching a Tensorflow program with the `--xla_dump_ir_to` flag, in particular I would like to explore how XLA handles parallelization.

I have a test program running on a machine with 56 CPUs, and in the resulting `.ll` file a parallelized function shows up, as expected:

```
call void @__xla_cpu_runtime_ParallelForkJoin(i8* %6, i8* %run_options, i8** null, i8** %buffer_table, i64* %prof_counters, i32 56, i64* getelementptr inbounds ([224 x i64], [224 x i64]* @parallel_convolution_parallel_dimension_partitions, i32 0, i32 0), i32 2, i8* bitcast (void (i8*, i8*, i8**, i8**, i64*, i64*)* @parallel_convolution to i8*))
```

Looking at the `ParallelForkJoin` function in XLA's source code there is an input parameter `num_partitions` that here is set to 56.

Now I would like to obtain a similar result that only uses some of the available CPUs, so I added the following lines to my python program (as suggested on the Tensorflow guide https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/overview#optimizing_for_cpu and elsewhere here on SO):

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.intra_op_parallelism_threads = 5
config.inter_op_parallelism_threads = 5
tf.Session(config=config)
```

but the generated `.ll` file is exactly the same!

Why is that? I would have thought that specifying a different number of parallel threads would lead to a parameter of 5 (in this case) instead of 56.

More in general, is there any documentation about how XLA extracts parallelism?

Comment: Did you find any answer for this question?

Comment: Not really. Apparently users are not supposed to handle parallelization details (I found something about it in a google group), and anyway I stopped trying to use XLA due to a number of other issues.